# How to check a radio button through jQuery which is rendered by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some radio buttons which are rendered by jQuery on ajax response. But `jQuery('input').prop('checked', true);` is not working.

Comment: `prop('checked', true)` should work fine. We need to see more of your code to help you. Are you sure you're calling that *after* you append the input to the DOM?

Comment: just make sure that you are calling this after your radio button are loaded from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Html

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="1" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#myCheck').prop('checked', 'true');
```

Comment: jQuery('input').prop('checked', true); will also work fine.

Comment: i wrote down the comment only nothing else.

Comment: I think its due to the fact that the input is rendered by jquery

Comment: Did you add jquery correctly to your page? Are you getting any error? Can you share more of your code please?